# combining multiple columns in to single columns in hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I have one table shown in below.

```
Id   v1  v2  v3
 A   01  03  23
 B   11  21  05
 C   02  10  24
 D   22  14  23
```

here first column has id and it's related with three columns. SO i have to combine that three column into one single column with related id.

For example.

```
id  value
A    01
A    03
A    23
B    11
B    21
B    05
.    ..
.    ..
```

So i have to done this in to hive so please let me know.

Comment: i tried  explode function but it's not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into table result_table select Id, v1 as value from orig_table;
insert into table result_table select Id, v2 as value from orig_table;
insert into table result_table select Id, v3 as value from orig_table;
select Id,value from result_table;
```

or

```
select Id, value 
       from orig_table LATERAL VIEW explode(array(v1,v2,v3)) orig_table_alias AS value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, v1
from table
union all
select id, v2
from table
union all
select id, v3
from table
```